# Sender score and side effects releated to mailinator.com or maildrop.cc

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, test-automation, reputation

I have looked around, however, I can't find accurate information if the Sender Score could be affected if I send hundreds of transactional emails daily to mailinator.com or maildrop.cc or any spam eater tool. I'm in a testing phase and sometimes I face a scenario where I need to send tons of emails through the Triggered Sends.

I recall from the past a previous discussion with a MarketingCloud representative because initially those emails are not reaching such domains. They explained us that in some way our reputation could be affected. We are using Triggered Sends.

So I have tried find anywhere some insights if really there are side effects of sending to domains like mailinator.com or maildrop.cc and if there's such testing permitted volume.

Can anyone point me to the correct place where to look at?

Answer (score 2):

The sender reputation is determined by the ISP/mail service of the recipient domain so if this is a reputation issue cannot be defined in general.

However several hundred sends are a pretty low volume and therefore in 90% of the cases this shouldn't be a problem at all. However the more consevative recommendations suggest gradually starting with as low as 50 emails per day and double volume afterwards. Others recommend to start with 5,000 emails per day when sending to sensitive providers.

To check if your sends have been bounced due to bad sender reputation or spammy content, check the tracking results of your send for *Block Bounces*.

**Further resources on IP warming:**

- [Salesforce Knowledge Base - Build reputation for new IP Addresses (warming guide)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240066&type=1)
- [SFMC Blog - New IP Address? Don't Forget to Ramp Up](https://www.marketingcloud.com/blog/new-ip-address-dont-forget-to-ramp-up/)
- [Sendgrid - IP Warmup Schedule (PDF)](https://sendgrid.com/docs/assets/IPWarmupSchedule.pdf)